# Differentiate vector norm by matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I've been trying to perform the following differentiation of a neural network:

$$\frac{\delta||h(XW)\alpha-y||^2}{\delta W} = \frac{\delta}{\delta W}\sum_i(h(XW)_i\alpha-y_i)^2$$

Where $X$ and $W$ and matrices, $\alpha$ and $y$ are vectors, and $h$ is a point wise applied function.

I've been reading the Wikipedia article on Matrix calculus and "The Matrix Cookbook" all day, but I can't seem to get things to work. I think it should probably be

$$2(h(XW)\alpha-y)\frac{\delta}{\delta W}(h(XW)\alpha)$$

But I certainly get stuck at the $h$ function, which I guess you could say is from matrix to matrix.

Any hints would be appreciated.

**Update:** I think this derivation is correct:

$$\frac{\delta||h(XW)\alpha-y||^2}{\delta W} = \frac{\delta}{\delta W}(h(XW)\alpha-y)^T(h(XW)\alpha-y) = 2(h(XW)\alpha-y)^T\frac{\delta}{\delta W}(h(XW)\alpha) = 2(h(XW)\alpha-y)^TX^Th'(XW)\alpha$$

This was derived by derivating over each element of $W$ using traces.

---

**Update 2:** I found this great presentation of the topic: [Schonemann_Trace_Derivatives_Presentation.pdf](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~nydic001/docs/unpubs/Schonemann_Trace_Derivatives_Presentation.pdf) which I recommend very much.

I've reformulated by defining $H=h(XW)$, $H'=h'(XW)$, $E = HA-Y$. Hence the problem has the pretty solution

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta W}||E||_F^2 = \frac{\delta}{\delta W}Tr(EE^T) = 2X^T(H' \odot EA^T)$$

Where $\odot$ is the point wise product. By working more with the trace manipulations you can also get a formula for the generalized problem $h(h(...)W_2)W_1)W_0$.

Comment: Did you mean "...$X$ and $W$ are matrices..." ?

Comment: You are right. Thanks, I've corrected it.

Comment: Thomas you are not serious. Your update 2 has nothing to do with your question. OK, I stop wasting my time.

Comment: loup, I don't understand. All I did was moving from vectors to matrices, so I could formulate the norm using traces. It's a pure generalization when considering vectors as one dimensional matrices.

Comment: Ah yes, it is a generalization ! Now, since we have a trace, using my answer, I can calculate the gradient ; one finds $\nabla_W(f)=2X^TH'^TEA^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas, here there are no traces. I assume that $h:M_n\rightarrow M_n$ and $||.||$ is the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The derivative of $h$, in the point $XW$, is denoted by  $D_{XW}h\in L(M_n,M_n)$ and is a jacobian. If $f:W\rightarrow ||h(XW)\alpha-y||^2$, then $D_{W}f:H\in M_n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a linear application. If $g:W\rightarrow h(XW)\alpha-y$, then $D_Wg:H\rightarrow D_{XW}h(XH)\alpha$. Finally the required derivative $D_Wf:H\rightarrow 2(h(XW)\alpha-y)^T(D_{XW}h)XH\alpha$ doesn't have a nice head.

$f$ is a real function and then, has a gradient that (theoretically)  we can write using the matrix scalar product $(U,V)=trace(U^TV)$. Unfortunately, "trace" does not appear in the formula giving $D_Wf$. I'm afraid that you have to settle for the previous result.

Answer (score 1):

In its second updated form, the function and its differential can be written in terms of the Frobenius product as
$$ \eqalign {
f &= E:E \cr
df &= 2\,E:dE \cr
   &= 2\,E:dHA \cr
   &= 2\,EA^T:dH \cr
   &= 2\,EA^T:H'\circ d(XW) \cr
   &= 2\,EA^T\circ H':XdW \cr
   &= 2\,X^T(EA^T\circ H'):dW \cr
} $$
Yielding the derivative as
$$ \eqalign {
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W} &= 2\,X^T(EA^T\circ H') \cr
} $$
The Hadamard product is commutative, so this equals Thomas' result.

Comment: The $\{E,A\}$ variables are specified to be vectors, therefore the Hadamard product can be eliminated in favor of diagonal matrices, yielding
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}
 = 2X^T\cdot{\rm Diag}(E)\cdot H'\cdot{\rm Diag}(A)
$$