# $() = | − |^2$ Compute the Hessian of f and show it is positive definite.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

$() = \| − \|^2$ , where $$ is an $ \times $ matrix with zero null space, $$ is an $$ dimensional vector, and the solution $x$ is an $$ dimensional vector.

$f'(x) = 2A|Ax-b|$, $f''(x)=2A^2$, the square is positive definite. Is this right?
How to compute the derivative for a matrix form?

Comment: According to your definition, $x$ must be a $n-$vector, so $f'$ does not make sense, since $f$ has $n$ variables. Try writing $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ to get a clear image of what is going on.

Comment: You presumably mean $\| Ax -b \|_{2}$ rather than $| Ax-b |$.  You can express $f(x)$ as $f(x)=(Ax-b)^{T}(Ax-b)=x^{T}(A^{T}A)x-2b^{T}A^{T}x+b^{T}b$.  From there you can find the gradient and Hessian of f.  The gradient is $\nabla f(x)=2A^{T}Ax$ and the Hessian is $\nabla^{2}f(x)=2A^{T}A$.

Comment: just looking at dimensions, $A^2$ does not exist when $m\neq n$

Answer (score 2):

I am combining [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606646/matrix-derivative-ax-btax-b?newreg=864461e3f4c14337a147f4c81da5745a), with Brian Borchers' answer.
The Jacobian is:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b) \ \  = \ \  2(Ax-b)^T\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(Ax-b) \ \  = \ \  2(Ax-b)^TA$$

The Hessian is simply:

$$ 2 A^TA$$

Could be worth checking out this [Matrix Cookbook](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf).