# Gradient of $f(x) = (Ax - b)^\mathsf{T} (Ax - b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, multilinear-algebra

I want to find the gradient of  $f(x) = (Ax - b)^\mathsf{T} (Ax - b)$, from product rule, I got:

$$
\mathrm{d}f(x) = (A \mathrm{d}x)^\mathsf{T}(Ax-b)+(Ax-b)^\mathsf{T}(A \mathrm{d}x)
$$
now I know I need to reformat the RHS to look like (something)$^\mathsf{T} \mathrm{d}x$, so that the something is the gradient I need to find. But I have trouble figuring how to get it to this form.

Comment: Please see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606646/matrix-derivative-ax-btax-b

Comment: Be careful about your matrix calculus layout choice (numerator layout, denominator layout, or a hybrid choice). If you are using numerator layout, then $\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = \left[\frac{\mathrm{d}f(\mathbf{x})}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}\right]^\mathsf{T}$, whereas in denominator layout $\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\mathrm{d}f(\mathbf{x})}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The linked question shows you how to take the derivative in coordinates, but I much prefer your approach using the differential. The last step you need is the observation that a scalar is always equal to its own transpose; you can use this to reorder the (scalar) first term so that the $dx$ goes to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the attachment that I attached to the answer.  [Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UVQw.jpg)

Comment: Please, write your answer using [MathJax notation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and avoid unnecessary links.