# what is the gradient of $||Ax -b||^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, linear-regression

I was trying to figure out the gradient descent approach of solving Ax-b for x. I have previously seen the closed form solution for x by minimizing $||Ax - b||^2$;

That gives the equation $x = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$

I was trying to derive this myself; however I see some conflicting answers. check out the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606646/matrix-derivative-ax-btax-b). The accepted answer, and the one below it, give different gradients.

1. gradient = $2A^T (Ax - b)$
2. gradient = $2(Ax - b)^T A$

The 2nd equation is transpose of the 1st. Is the second equation wrong?
What is the gradient of the given cost function? is it the first equation?

However, when I minimize it by equating it to 0,
I get the same closed form equation for x

i.e, $x = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$

I am not very familiar with vector calculus, and I might be asking a novice question.
Any incite is helpful, thanks :)

Comment: The first one is correct, the second one is not unless you are using [convention from matrix calculus (numerator layout notation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector) instead.

Comment: The gradient is a vector, hence a column. The derivative is a linear map, hence the transpose of the gradient.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks, I calculated the gradient in denominator layout and it matches the 1st equation.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you explain why a derivative will be a transpose of a gradient? in my head they mean the same thing? no?

Comment: Try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5PsLJbeiNE&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd&index=26&t=1875s).