# Matrix derivative with respect to matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus

Say I have a $ 2 \times 2$ matrix as $A$ and a $2 \times 1$ vector as $X$.
I want the derivative of the matrix product with represent to $A$:

Let $y=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2
\end{bmatrix}$

Then what is $\frac{dy}{dA}$?

According to the standard definition of Jacobian [image]

I should be getting a $ 2 \times 4$ matrix where columns are $a,b,c,d$ but this does not agree with the material I am reading. Is the transpose involved in any of this?

Comment: What is $A$? Is it a scalar, a vector, a matrix?

Comment: A is the 2*2 matrix with entries $a,b,c,d$

Comment: do you mean $dy/dx$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $A\mapsto Ax$ is linear, so everything is trivial.

If you really want to write the Jacobian in coordinates, it's
$$
J=\begin{pmatrix}
x1 & x2& 0& 0\\
0& 0&x1&x2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
because, as you may check yourself, we have 
$$
Jvec(B)= Bx
$$
for any matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$ with vectorization $vec({B})\in\mathbb{R}^4$

Answer (score 2):

Begin with the equation and it differential.
$$\eqalign{y &= A\cdot x \\ dy &= dA\cdot x}$$
One method to calculate the derivative is to flatten the matrix term using [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations).
$$\eqalign{
dy &= (x^T\otimes I)\cdot da \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial a} &= (x^T\otimes I) 
}$$
Another approach is to employ index notation (and [Einstein's convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation))
$$\eqalign{
dy_i &= dA_{ij}\,x_j \\
\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial A_{mn}}
 &= \bigg(\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{mn}}\bigg)\,x_j
  = \big(\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}\big)\,x_j 
  = \delta_{im}\,x_n \\
}$$
Yet another idea is to define an isotropic fourth-order tensor as the dyadic product $(\star)$ of two identity matrices $\,({\cal E}=I\!\star\!I)\,$  and dispense with the indices altogether.
$$\eqalign{
dy &= dA\cdot x &= ({\cal E}\cdot x):dA \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial A} &= {\cal E}\cdot x &= I \star x \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that matrix calculus can always be re-expressed in non-matrix form by performing the appropriate multiplications. Then you can take the derivatives. This simplified your life a lot (and the overall comprehension) in cases like this one.

Consider that “taking the derivative with respect to a matrix” means de facto taking the derivatives of that expression with respect to each element of the matrix. In this case, you want to derivate $Ax$ by each element of A. Which is trivial if you write down the result of the product $Ax$ and derivate with respect to each of the 4 elements of A. [This source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622195/taking-a-derivative-with-respect-to-a-matrix#622200) can help you understand a little bit better as well as the bottom of page 10 of [this matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The Jacobian, the way you wrote it, really only works after vectorizing w.r.t. the components of $A$. More generally, given a function $f\colon X\to Y$, you can think of the derivative as a $(\operatorname{rank} Y, \operatorname{rank}  X)$-tensor, which allows one to keep the matrix structure of the input here.

In this case, since the input is a matrix, i.e. a rank-$2$ tensor, and the output is a vector, i.e. a rank-$1$ tensor, you can think of $dy/dA$ the (1, 2) tensor with components

$$\Big(\frac{\rm d y}{\rm d A}\Big)^k_{ij}=\frac{\partial y_k}{\partial A_{ij}} \leadsto D = \frac{\rm d y}{\rm d A} = \begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ 0& 0\end{bmatrix},  \begin{bmatrix}0& 0 \\ x_1 & x_2\end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}$$

This tensor encodes a linear map given by the corresponding tensor contraction

$$D\cdot X = \sum_{ij} D^{k}_{ij} X^{ij}$$

In particular, note that for $f(A)=Ax$ we have the first order Taylor expansion

$$ T_f^{(1)}(A) = f(0) + Df(0)\cdot A =\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix}A_{11}x_1 + A_{12}x_2 \\ A_{21}x_1 + A_{22}x_2\end{bmatrix} = f(A)$$

I.e. the function is in fact equal to its first order Taylor expansion, as expected, since it's a linear function.